# Text search in stored proc SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Does any one know the script to use for text search in SQL Server? I would like to search a text from all the stored proc inside the SQL Server, does anyone know what is the script I should use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES or syscomments are **not** reliable.

The text field is nvarchar(4000) for both (over multiple rows syscomments only). So your search text can be lost on the boundary for a syscomments or never found for INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES

[`sys.sql_modules`.definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081(SQL.90).aspx) is nvarchar(max)

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
FROM
    sys.sql_modules
WHERE
    definition LIKE '%mytext%'
```

Edit, Oct 2011

Bringing this answer up to date.

[Red Gate SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) is a **free** SSMS plug in that is quite useful.

Comment: +1 for discouraging the use of `sys.syscomments`. [This](https://visakhm.blogspot.in/2012/03/advantages-of-using-syssqlmodules-view.html) blog details few more reasons as to why we should be using `sys.sql_modules`.

Answer (score 2):

Updated: There are several equivalent ways. Here's one:

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id) 
FROM 
    sys.sql_modules 
WHERE 
    Definition LIKE '%searchtext%' 
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'IsProcedure') = 1
```

Comment: -1 This is not equivalent to sys.sql_modules or OBJECT_DEFINITION because it may not work... the ROUTINE_DEFINITION may not have the while proc code

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: it was *wrong* when I posted: you just edited to correct it. You have down voted my *correct* answer...

Comment: @gbn - if you downvote this answer, you should have downvoted the syscomments answer to. The fact that you didn't makes it look very selective. I can understand Mitch being annoyed by that, I know I would be.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, @Lieven: The implied trust in user with 76k rep makes it an authoritative answer, with more weight than an answer from a 300 rep user. It seems unfair to me to downvote the 300 rep user (when practically the answer will be ignored anyway). If Jon Skeet had posted a "syscomments" no amount of counter examples would help correct the mis-information. Anyway, downvote removed

Comment: @gbn: fair enough, I assumed the worst. *Some defect in my character*

Answer (score 2):

You can use as well:

```
select distinct object_name(id) from sys.syscomments where text like '%SearchTextHere%'
```

Comment: It is better to use `sys.sql_modules` when compared with `sys.syscomments` due to several reasons mentioned [here](https://visakhm.blogspot.in/2012/03/advantages-of-using-syssqlmodules-view.html). `sys.syscomments` breaks the definition of a stored procedure over multiple rows if the length of the definition text exceeds 4000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to search for text through the stored procedures themselves?

Or table data?

If table data, how about [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)?