# search all stored procs for a literal or string

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to search for a string or literal in all stored procedures for a particular database in Microsoft SQL Server 2008?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text search in stored proc SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812962/text-search-in-stored-proc-sql-server)

Comment: This has been asked here sooooo many times already. Didn't the question search come up with suitable results?

Comment: Actually, search doesn't show up any related questions for that subject.

Comment: @Lasse - bug in search? Something for Meta?

Comment: @Oded @Lasse Bug in search? I can never find anything useful in search. I always do a site:stackoverflow.com from a web search engine!!

Comment: @David - it was supposed to have been hugely improved with the switch to Lucent.

Comment: @Oded Have you seen an improvement?

Comment: @David - I have, though like you I tend to use site: on google...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select quotename(s.name)+'.'+quotename(o.name) as object_name, o.type_desc
    from sys.sql_modules m
        inner join sys.objects o 
            on m.object_id = o.object_id
                and o.type = 'P' /* stored procuedure */
        inner join sys.schemas s 
            on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
    where m.definition like '%YourSearchText%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Grab yourself a copy of the **free** [Red-Gate SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) tool and start enjoying searching in SQL Server! :-)

[image]

It's a great and very useful tool, and **YES!** it's totally, absolutely FREE for any kind of use.

Comment: This is the BEST tool! I have used it since it was released!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%lq_Campaign%' 
AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```

Here is the a [link](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/search-stored-procedures/) I found on it.