# Determine table referenced in a view in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How can i get to know the tables used in a view in SQL Server? Is there a script or a tool that could let me know the tables used in a view and can also list down the fields?

Hope this clears the question. Let me know if not.

Please guide! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text search in stored proc SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812962/text-search-in-stored-proc-sql-server). you can find dependencies but not get the field list too

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate of [Text search in stored proc SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812962/text-search-in-stored-proc-sql-server). Separate answer exists. Please don't vote for close.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select
  cols.*
from
  sys.sql_expression_dependencies objs
  outer apply sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ( OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objs.referencing_id) + N'.' + object_name(objs.referencing_id), N'OBJECT' ) as cols
where
  objs.referencing_id = object_id('view_name_here')
```

Reference: [sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677185.aspx)
.

Comment: GSerg; thanks for that. From where did you got that script? Because the script returns null for all the columns

Comment: @Xorpower I just wrote it, having looked up the required sysview in BOL. It does work, table names are in `referenced_entity_name` and column names are in `referenced_minor_name`. If it doesn't for you, try providing a more qualified name of the view (such as `dbo.view_name`) or recompiling the view before examining it.

Comment: This works only if a view has another view being referenced into it. The reference_entity_name shows the another view being referred in my case and not the table name. Yes column name are in ref_minor_name.

Comment: @Xorpower Then there are other issues with your database. The query does show all referenced tables and views. To double-check, download [SQL Manager for SQL Server](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/mssql/manager/download) (free version), open up your view and switch to Dependecies tab.

Comment: Why not just `select referenced_entity_name,referenced_minor_name
from sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ( 'dbo.foo', N'OBJECT' )
where referenced_minor_name is not null`? The `OUTER APPLY` just seems to bring in additional rows as it is repeatedly called with the same values.

Comment: Martin, your script actually works! But is there a way to know whether the entity name is a table or a view? I have a view that references to some other view.

Comment: GSerg: the dependency tab in the SQL Manager comes blank.

Comment: @Xorpower That is the problem. It shouldn't. Try [executing `sp_refreshview` for all views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx).

Comment: @MartinSmith You're correct, I took that out from a bigger script that analysed multiple objects at once. Still, the data should be the same (*not true, but true enough*). If `outer apply` yields no data whereas a direct call does, then `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` doesn't contain any rows for which `outer apply` could have been called. That's an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to see the content of (most) objects would be:

```
sp_helptext blah
```

Where you substitute blah with the name of the object. This would yield the actual code which created the object. in this case, for instance it could result in:

```
CREATE VIEW blah
AS
  select blah.column1,blah.column2 from blah_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Using below simple query you can know which tables are used in view:

```
SELECT view_name, Table_Name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
WHERE View_Name = 'ViewName'
```

Answer (score 0):

This information is available from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA

```
SELECT * 
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE AS cu
    JOIN    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
    ON      c.TABLE_SCHEMA  = cu.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND     c.TABLE_CATALOG = cu.TABLE_CATALOG
    AND     c.TABLE_NAME    = cu.TABLE_NAME
    AND     c.COLUMN_NAME   = cu.COLUMN_NAME
    WHERE   cu.VIEW_NAME    = 'viewtablename';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use DISTINCT to get only the tables.

```
  Select   DISTINCT cols.referenced_entity_name from  
   sys.sql_expression_dependencies objs   outer apply
   sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities (
   OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objs.referencing_id) + N'.' +
   object_name(objs.referencing_id), N'OBJECT' ) as cols where  
   objs.referencing_id = object_id('viewname')
```